# Adding shapes to Canvas. How to bind to VM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, shapes

Sorry that the title is a bit vague but I could'n come up with a better one.

For arguments sake let's say I'm developing a simple drawing application, where the user just clicks and drags to draw a line (I'm not really developing that, but just to keep it simple).

I have a custom shape for the line to draw. Now I want to add new lines to the view as needed, but I'd like to use an `ObservableCollection` property via data binding on the view model to do that. Usaully I would use an `ItemsControl`. But of course the `ItemsControl` automatically positions it's items, which is not what I want.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that? Is there a way to disable the layout functions of an `ItemsControl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of an `ItemsControl` so it uses a `Canvas` instead of a `StackPanel` to hold its items, then use the `ItemContainerStyle` to bind the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties to your data object to position them.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have a blog article about the [ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) that explains in more detail how an `ItemsControl` works if you're interested.